# How to use an emoji as prefix instead of "/" on Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I'm trying to write a Telegram bot to help a friend with his online buisness.
I'm trying to make an interactive menu, but if I try to use an emoji as a prefix the `@bot.message_handler` doesn't read the user input, resulting in the menu not updating.

Working code (with "/" as command prefix):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["Menu"])
def startMenu(msg):

    #########-START MENU-#########
    markup = keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    btnHelp = types.KeyboardButton("/Help")
    ##############################
    
    markup.add(btnHelp)
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, text="Need help?"
                     , reply_markup=markup)
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=["Help"])
def helpMenu(msg):
    markup = keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    btnBack = types.KeyboardButton("/Menu")
    markup.add(btnBack)
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, text="Test Help"
                     , reply_markup=markup)
```

Faulty code (with UNICODE emoji as prefix):

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=["Menu"])
def startMenu(msg):

    #########-START MENU-#########
    markup = keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    btnHelp = types.KeyboardButton("\U0001F60Help")
    ##############################
    
    markup.add(btnHelp)
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, text="Need help?"
                     , reply_markup=markup)
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=["\U0001F60Help"])
def helpMenu(msg):
    markup = keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    btnBack = types.KeyboardButton("/Menu")
    markup.add(btnBack)
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, text="Test Help"
                     , reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression as there is no native way to change the prefixes:

```py
@bot.message_handler(regexp="^\U0001F60H(your_command)")
```